# Why am I receiving this NameError: when attempting to add an outlooks email Attachment's FileName to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com

I have a script that iterates over a folder in my outlook account, and then writes each emails metadata to a csv file. I am stuck on getting the attachments filename in the data. I keep receiving a NameError.

Here is my code:

```
import win32com.client
import datetime as date

# Input
f = open("testfile.txt", "w+")


outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders.Item("TestFolder")
inbox = folder.Folders.Item("Inbox")
msg = inbox.Items

# Process
list = []

for x in msg:
    senderEmail = x.SenderEmailAddress
    sender = x.SenderName
    subject = x.Subject
    if x.Attachments:
        for f in x.Attachments:
            attachment = f.FileName
    sum = [subject, sender, senderEmail, attachment]
    list.extend(sum)
```

Here is the error I keep receiving:

[image]

Any idea as to why I keep receiving this error?

Comment: `attachment` is only set if `x.Attachments` is non-empty. Also, `attachment` is overwritten on every iteration of the `for f in x.Attachments` loop. Did you mean to add all the `attachment`s to a list?

Comment: Yep, because for each email I want to show the filename of the attachment if there is one.

Comment: if `x.Attachments`doesn't exists then it doesn't create `attachment` and you may need `else: sum = [subject, sender, senderEmail]` without `attachment` Or you have to set `else: attachment = None`. OR maybe you should change indentation and do it inside `if` or maybe inside `for f`

Answer (score 0):

If `x.Attachments` doesn't exists then it doesn't create `attachment` but you try to use it.

If you want to create `sum` only when there is attachment then you should change indentations

```
if x.Attachments:
     for f in x.Attachments:
         attachment = f.FileName
         sum = [subject, sender, senderEmail, attachment]
         #list.extend(sum)
         list.append(sum)
```

If you want to create also when there is no `attachment` then you need `else`

Eventually you can use `None` for `attachment` and it will be easier to work with list which have the same number of items.

```
if x.Attachments:
     for f in x.Attachments:
         attachment = f.FileName
         sum = [subject, sender, senderEmail, attachment]
         #list.extend(sum)
         list.append(sum)
 else:
     sum = [subject, sender, senderEmail, None]
     #list.extend(sum)
     list.append(sum)
```